# Mac OS X: Setting up Xcode to use Ant results in permission errors

Tags: java, xcode, ant

I'm trying to setup Xcode as my primary IDE to work with our existing projects but running into some permissions problems.

Our projects are java based and we use ant to build the jar and it all runs under Tomcat.

Up until now, I have been working strictly from the terminal and a text editor. This has been working fine, but I'm trying to get the Xcode IDE integrated to streamline the development process a bit.

I have my deploy scripts that I wrote and work great, so there's no problem in my existing process(other than that its a little cumbersome).

I created a new empty project in Xcode and created a target that runs the ant build command and make file for one of our projects. I usually run the build command as:

```
sudo ant -q -f /pathto/build.xml clean dist-debug
```

This cleans for each build and helps to prevent odd problems. The sudo part is what's catching me right now.

When I run the build in Xcode, it start but fails when trying to do the clean. I get file permissions problems. I have gone in and set the permissions to 777 on the directory and its contents and changed the group to my user account but it still fails the same way.

Any recommendations on how to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. I was getting an identical permission error when trying to use the ant dist-debug in the terminal in the project directory.

Because my build scripts were using sudo there were remnants after each build that could only be cleaned out by another sudo rm command. After I went through and manually deleted the cruft from the project directories, I was able to run the command successfully in terminal. Then I ran it using Xcode and it worked perfectly.